# Carousel Image Sliding Out Becomes White on Safari using bootstrap 4 Angular 2

Tags: html, css, angular, carousel, bootstrap-4

So there's like a tearing or flickering effect when the carousel slides left, as if the image disappears somewhere too far left, and a white space appears instead of it. I tried to add overflow: hidden or width: 100% but that didn't really work either.

The thing is, it works very well on Chrome; the effect only happens on Safari.

Here is my component scss and html files:

```css
/* Make the carousel take the full screen height */

.fullscreen {
  height: 100vh;
  .carousel-inner {
    .carousel-item {
      height: 100vh;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="landingCarousel" class="carousel slide fullscreen" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#landingCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#landingCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#landingCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="../assets/images/s1.jpg">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h1 class="text-uppercase">Slide1</h1>
        <p>Slide 1 text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="../assets/images/s2.jpg">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h1 class="text-uppercase">Slide 2</h1>
        <p>Slide 2 text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="../assets/images/s3.jpg">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h1 class="text-uppercase">Slide 3</h1>
        <p>Slide 3 text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#landingCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#landingCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: are there some CSS styles that are applied only to the Safari Version and not to the Chrome/Mozilla version? Or Style that are not applied to Safari? You can check this with the developer toolbar on that div/html tag. I think this is only connected to css? right?

Comment: Nope, no css styles applied only to Safari; they're both (Safari and Chrome) identical.